# Shortcode not being executed

Tags: shortcode

I place the following code within the WP 'init' callback (or when plugins are loaded).

```
add_shortcode('my_shortcode',
               function($atts, $content ='') { die(); }
             );
if (!shortcode_exists('my_shortcode')) die();
```

In my page I put "**[my_shortcode]**"

When I view the page I get "****"

Any idea what happened to my code?

---

Update:
I have simplified the problem.

I added the shortcode definition in my theme's index.php file.

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package GeneratePress
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

add_shortcode('myt_active_plugins',
             function($atts, $content, $name) {
                    return 'Shortcode injected';
                  }
            );
```

I deactivated all plugins.

I (re)installed WP3.5.2

I created a post:

```
Welcome *[myt_active_plugins]*
```

I published the post and when I viewed it I got:

```
Welcome **
```

As a final check I installed a shortcode plugin, (Shortcodes Ultimate) and it acted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

1. By using `die` function, You are stopping the process and it will stop immediately after running the shortcode callback. Better to let the rest of the code to be executed.
2. You need to return something in shortcode callback function instead of sending headers using `die` or `echo`.

So, change your code to something like the following one and it should work. You are free to wrap it in `init` hook.

```
add_shortcode(
    'my_shortcode',
    function($atts, $content ='') {
        return 'This is from My shortcode!';
    }
);
```

3. The condition for checking shortcode existence is problematic. If you want to check if a certain shortcode exists in a page, `has_shortcode` function. Check `has_shortcode` document [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_shortcode/).

Comment: Hector: Tried that. The die() instructions are just my debugging technique of last resort, used to verify that the program execution is or is not reaching that point. The first die() not being executed proves that WP thinks I have created the shortcut correctly. The second die() not being executed proves that my callback code was not being invoked. But some how WP still replaces the shortcode!

Comment: You can enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and then use `error_log('something');` instead of `die`. BTW, does it work?

Comment: Mohammed: Thats how I originally tried it, but my code was in as class and in a namespace, so I returned to the simpler way using the closure. In all cases wp reports that the shortcode exists but fails to actuall call the callback.

Comment: Hector: I just tried WP_DEBUG ad it reported several unrelated errors which I fixed. The problem remains. I Added the logging you suggested but don't know where to find the resulting log. In any event, if the die() code were being reached, the resulting termination of the program would surely result in not displaying the page (which I'd notice!)

Comment: Hector: point 3: I was just checking if I had correctly registered the shortcode with WP. I feel certain that the page has the shortcode text because when I view the page it has been removed, as if WP had called the shortcode callback and received nothiing. If the callback returns a string instead of dying, the result is the same - the shortcode is just removed from the page.

Comment: Check debug.log file under wp-content folder.

Comment: No errors in log.

Comment: Please paste full code in the question.

Comment: The code in question is part of a 2Mb plugin. I could provide the  most proximate functions but that doesn't seem to work in this reply box. I have insufficient reputation to go to chat. Perhaps I should answer my own question?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the class or related codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that.

```
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function( $content ) 
{
    ob_start();
    // do something to $content
    echo $content;
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Same problem. Basically WP sees my shortcode as valid and replaces it with an empty string, but does not execute the callback!

Comment: What are you passing in the function parameters?

Comment: My code is just as above. add_shortcode is called with a string, and a callback function. add_shortcode('my-shortcode',  my-callback);

Comment: Then you may try this one
`code`
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function');
function my_shortcode_function( $content ) 
{
    ob_start();
    // do something to $content
    echo $content;
    return ob_get_clean();
}

Comment: Whatever I put in my_shortcode_function() never gets executed. Even a die(); instruction has no effect.  WP is recognizing the shortcode and replacing it without ever calling my callback function.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? And how you call it? This code is working for me.

Comment: See my edit to the original post.  I think this will just have to remain a mystery. Meanwhile I can work-around by using a content filter and a regex.

Comment: I think there is a problem, use the shortcode function in your functions.php file and call it in index.php

Comment: I'm going to assume that the Shortcodes Ultimate plugin does things correctly(800,000 installs, 5-star ratings on over 5000 reviews), and get on with other things. This must have something to do with my local server (Wampserver). Thank you, and Hector, for your efforts.